# Selecting a data frame row using a term in list found in the same data frame row

Tags: python, pandas, search

I have a data frame that has two columns. One column host a term's name and the second column is a list of terms associated with the 1st column. It generally looks like this:

```
Name      Terms
Jupiter    [5,planet, big,]
June       [month,6,hot]
Neptune    [blue, planet,big]
Seventeen  [17, number,teen]
Whale      [animal, big, swim]
```

What I want to do is find terms in the 1st column by searching/querying the second column. So for example, if I were to search for Terms == 'planet', I want to return a either a list containing both Jupiter and Neptune, or part of the date frame that contains the two planets. How would I be able to do this in Python?

Comment: try this, ```df[df['Terms'].apply(lambda x : True if "planet" in x else False)]```

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `explode`:

```
df.loc[df.explode('Terms').query('Terms == "planet"').index]
```

Output:

```
      Name                Terms
0  Jupiter     [5, planet, big]
2  Neptune  [blue, planet, big]
```

---

Or nested list comprehension

```
df.loc[[any(n == 'planet' for n in i) for i in df['Terms']]]
```

Output:

```
      Name                Terms
0  Jupiter     [5, planet, big]
2  Neptune  [blue, planet, big]
```

Timings:

```
%timeit df.loc[df.explode('Terms').query('Terms == "planet"').index]
7.07 ms ± 95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df[df['Terms'].apply(lambda x : True if "Planet" in x else False)]
861 µs ± 43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.loc[[any(n == 'planet' for n in i) for i in df['Terms']]]
674 µs ± 33.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot!